# Nginx does not stop with websocket connection

Tags: nginx, websocket

I have nginx 1.6.2 wih configuration to upgrade connection to websocket.

```
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

When no websocket connection is opened, "service nginx stop" works, both master and worker process are gracefully stopped.

```
    killproc $prog -QUIT
```

But when I have an opened websocket, nginx cannot be stopped, even though I get :

```
Stopping nginx:                                            [  OK  ]
```

I tried :

> killproc $prog -KILL

but as expected, it forcefully kill the master the first time I run the command, and the worker if I re-execute.

What do you recommend for forcing a shutdown on nginx ? I'm thinking of replacing killproc by :

> pkill $prog

Comment: Try to use `TERM` or `INT` instead of `KILL`. http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html

Try to use `TERM` or `INT` instead of `KILL`.
`KILL` is too "fast", it doesn't give nginx's master a chance to stop workers.